# Are there any open source console/parser APIs for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, console

My boss frequently asks me to tweak colors for our iOS application.  This usually involves me repeatedly having to create a new build and deploy it to his iPad.

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented some kind of console view with some kind of parser that can handle making changes at runtime?  I'd like to just change the colors (and other "stuff") on the fly without much fuss.

Ideally I'd like to just type in a natural objective-c command, but if that is too complicated I can just use a scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there is [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/) and [NSExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html)

`NSExpression` is really great for math & comparison operations, but I haven't used it much past that.

Comment: I'll take a look at ParseKit...I've worked with BNF-style grammars before and I think ParseKit may be useful.